# How to prevent page from refreshing after ajax submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I just started using Ajax function in my work and I'm not very familiar with it. I have this problem that when I submit data, it submits without refreshing the page, but on a second time when trying to submit, the page refreshes before submitting. I've used the e.preventDefault() to prevent the page from refreshing but it is not working for me. It just seems there is something I'm not doing right.

This is my Ajax code

```
<!--AJAX PROCESS TO SUBMIT CHECKED COURSES-->
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadNewCourse();
        loadDelTable();
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            $('#form').submit(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
                var in_arr = [],
                    name = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>"),
                    email = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>"),
                    regno = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['regno']?>"),
                    level = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['level']?>"),
                    dept = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['dept']?>"),
                    semester = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['semester']?>");
                    $('.inChk').each(function(i){
                        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
                        if(checked){
                            in_arr.push($(this).val());
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'submit.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    data: {
                        post_inId : in_arr,
                        name : name,
                        email : email,
                        regno : regno,
                        level : level,
                        dept : dept,
                        semester : semester
                        },
                    success: function(data){
                        loadNewCourse();
                        loadDelTable();
                        // setTimeout(function(){
                        //     $('#regModal').modal('hide');
                        // }, 1000);
                        $('body').removeAttr('style');
                        $('#regModal').removeAttr('style');
                        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                        swal({
                            // "Success", "Registration successful", "success"
                            position: "top-end",
                            type: "success",
                            title: "Registration successful",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2000
                        })
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        swal("Oops...", "Registration failed.", "error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PROCESS AJAX DELETE ON CHECKBOX SELECT
$('#deleteCheck').click(function(){
    $('#delform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        var id_arr = [],
            regno = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['regno']?>"),
            level = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['level']?>");
        $('.delChk').each(function(i){
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if(checked){
                id_arr.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        swal({
                title: "Are you sure you want to delete selected courses?",
                text: "You can add these courses by registering again!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function(isConfirm){
                if(isConfirm){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "submit.php",
                    data: {
                        post_id : id_arr,
                        regno : regno,
                        level : level
                        },
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        // console.log(data);
                        loadDelTable();
                        loadNewCourse();
                        swal({
                                // "Success", "Registration successful", "success"
                                position: "top-end",
                                type: "success",
                                title: "Delete successful",
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                                timer: 2000
                            })
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        swal("Oops...", "Delete failed.", "error");
                    }
                });
            }else{
                // alert('isNotConfirm and is not success');
                swal("Oops...", "Delete failed", "error");
            }
        });
        return false;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    });
});

    function loadNewCourse(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'processReg.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: {
                loadit : 1
            },
            success: function(disp){
                $("#reveal").html(disp).show();
            }
        });
    }
    
    function loadDelTable(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete_tbl.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: {
                loadDel : 1
            },
            success: function(deldisp){
                $("#showRegtbl").html(deldisp).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the page displaying submitted data

```
 <div class="" style="margin:auto;margin-top:0;text-align:center">
            <div class="" >
                <h2 class="#" style="font-family: 'proxima-nova','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;letter-spacing:5px;font-weight:100;color:#061931;">Welcome!</h2>
                <p style="width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:center;padding:5px;background:whitesmoke;padding:20px;">If this is your first visit, click on <b>Register Courses</b> to register courses available for you. <br>If you are re-visiting, you can continue where you left off.<br><a href="#regModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regModal"><span class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style="letter-spacing:3px;margin-top:10px;"><b>Register Courses</b></span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div><br>
            <!--Display Courses that are available-->
                <span id="reveal"></span>

            <!--Table to display courses registered-->
                <span id="showRegtbl"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been stuck in this for more than 3days now. Can anyone here help me out pls?

Comment: You shouldn't have `$("#form").submit()` inside `$("#submit").click()`. Just use `$("#form").submit()`.

Comment: exactly @Barmar!! it will bind the submit event the number of time click is fired.

Comment: @Barmar, how then do I tell the script which button is clicked without the button click event? $("#submit").click() is the button that is clicked before the form submits. Can u please put me through how to do that?

Comment: @NdongesitEdet `$('#form').submit(function(e)` is enough to determine if the form got submit, and remember the form should be a valid submitable form.

Comment: I've used just the `$("#submit").click()` but it still does the same thing. @Barmar

Comment: @MohammedKhurram, yeah it submits well at first but when trying to submit a second time, it attempts refreshing the page and doesn't submit again. At that time the page is refreshed, then try submitting and it works, try again and the page is refreshed without submitting. That's just how the flow is...

Comment: @NdongesitEdet refer to the answer and tell me if you still have any doubt.

Comment: If you need to do different things depending on the submit button, just use the `click` event, don't use the `submit` event. It's one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `$("#form").submit(function() { ... })` creates a handler for the *next* time the form is submitted. Doing this inside the handler for `$("#submit").click()` is not correct. Clicking the submit button will establish a handler for the next submission, but then the default action will submit the form immediately, which refreshes the page. Putting `e.preventDefault()` inside the click handlers would prevent the reload, but then you would have to click twice to submit the form (and this wouldn't actually work, because the default action of a submit button is to trigger the submit event, and you're preventing that).

Just create submit handlers for each form, without doing it inside a click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadNewCourse();
  loadDelTable();
  $('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var in_arr = [],
      name = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['name']?>"),
      email = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>"),
      regno = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['regno']?>"),
      level = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['level']?>"),
      dept = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['dept']?>"),
      semester = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['semester']?>");
    $('.inChk').each(function(i) {
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if (checked) {
        in_arr.push($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: 'submit.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: {
        post_inId: in_arr,
        name: name,
        email: email,
        regno: regno,
        level: level,
        dept: dept,
        semester: semester
      },
      success: function(data) {
        loadNewCourse();
        loadDelTable();
        // setTimeout(function(){
        //     $('#regModal').modal('hide');
        // }, 1000);
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('#regModal').removeAttr('style');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        swal({
          // "Success", "Registration successful", "success"
          position: "top-end",
          type: "success",
          title: "Registration successful",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
        })
      },
      error: function(data) {
        swal("Oops...", "Registration failed.", "error");
      }
    });
  });

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // PROCESS AJAX DELETE ON CHECKBOX SELECT
  $('#delform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_arr = [],
      regno = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['regno']?>"),
      level = ("<?php echo $_SESSION['level']?>");
    $('.delChk').each(function(i) {
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if (checked) {
        id_arr.push($(this).val());
      }
    });
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete selected courses?",
        text: "You can add these courses by registering again!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
        closeOnConfirm: false
      },
      function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: {
              post_id: id_arr,
              regno: regno,
              level: level
            },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
              // console.log(data);
              loadDelTable();
              loadNewCourse();
              swal({
                // "Success", "Registration successful", "success"
                position: "top-end",
                type: "success",
                title: "Delete successful",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000
              })
            },
            error: function(data) {
              swal("Oops...", "Delete failed.", "error");
            }
          });
        } else {
          // alert('isNotConfirm and is not success');
          swal("Oops...", "Delete failed", "error");
        }
      });
    return false;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  });

  function loadNewCourse() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'processReg.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: {
        loadit: 1
      },
      success: function(disp) {
        $("#reveal").html(disp).show();
      }
    });
  }

  function loadDelTable() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'delete_tbl.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: {
        loadDel: 1
      },
      success: function(deldisp) {
        $("#showRegtbl").html(deldisp).show();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

If you had multiple submit buttons in the same form you would instead assign `click` handlers to each button, but *not* create `submit` handlers for the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the submission of the form and even handling.

The default action of the form ie submit can be done with `input type="submit"` or `<button>`

**The default**

```html
<h2> Form default action </h2>

<form action="">
<input type="hidden" id="someInput" value="hey">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

To prevent form's default action you can do 2 things.

**Avoid using `type="submit"` or button**

Do something like this

```js
function customForm(){
 alert("Hey this is custom handler, dont worry page will not refresh...!");
}
```

```html
<h2> Form with custom action </h2>

<form action="">
<input type="hidden" id="someInput" value="hey">
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="customForm()">
</form>
```

**Use event.preventDefault()**

```js
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert("custom handler with preventDefault(), no reload no worries...!");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Form with custom handler using preventDefault() </h2>

<form id="myform" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="someInput" value="hey">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="customForm(this)">
</form>
```

For any queries comment down.

Comment: what you're demonstrating is true and well understood. I've applied same to my work but for some reasons that I can't figure out, the page still refreshes on submit after the first Ajax submit without refresh. @Mohammed Khurram

Comment: Do some debugging at your end, I don't see anything wrong with ajax call, do not use `$("#submit").click()` better go with `$('#form').submit(function(e)` just as in Barmar's answer. @NdongesitEdet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the assistance. I did some debugging on my end and was able to fix the issue by removing the form tags from the Add and Delete scripts and then include them in the page displaying the submitted data.
Like this...

```
<div class="" style="margin:auto;margin-top:0;text-align:center">
            <div class="" >
                <h2 class="#" style="font-family: 'proxima-nova','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;letter-spacing:5px;font-weight:100;color:#061931;">Welcome!</h2>
                <p style="width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:center;padding:5px;background:whitesmoke;padding:20px;">If this is your first visit, click on <b>Register Courses</b> to register courses available for you. <br>If you are re-visiting, you can continue where you left off.<br><a href="#regModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regModal"><span class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style="letter-spacing:3px;margin-top:10px;"><b>Register Courses</b></span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div><br>
  <!--Display Courses that are available-->
<form id='form' action='POST' href='#'>
   <span id="reveal"></span>
</form>

<!--Table to display courses registered-->
<form id='delform' action='POST' href='#'>
   <span id="showRegtbl"></span>
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a more proper way to do this or this is just okay? Thank you for the help so far.